# Is there a way to access LinkedIn API without a user

Tags: rest, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm building an application that gets data from LinkedIn using the REST API. When my user has a LinkedIn account, I use OAuth to authenticate and access the data on the user's behalf.

My problem is when the user doesn't have LinkedIn account. In such a case, I'd like to fallback to anonymous access and get very basic (and public) information from LinkedIn.

I saw in some other questions and discussions that in general, LinkedIn does not permit anonymous access to its API, but I also saw some hints about some APIs available also anonymously.

Is there absolutely no way to get any type of data out of LinkedIn
    API anonymously? Even the most basic data anyone could see in a
    user's public profile without logging in?

Comment: when i go to this URL it gives me first 10 profiles 

https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=<FirstName>&last=<LastName>&trk=prof-samename-search-submit Can i get more than 10 by  any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Terms of Use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use), it is not permitted to display API data to a non-authenticated user (section III(A)(1), III(A)(2)(g)). All data pulled from the API should be pulled by an authenticated user, using their OAuth credentials.

In terms of showing basic profile data anonymously, the [Member Profile plugin](http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile-plugin-generator?button-type-inline=true) was designed to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It appears that this is the right direction. I'm trying to show the current user the basic profiles of other users. It appears that in order to use the plugin, I need at least the public profile URL of the other users. As far as I could understand from the terms of use, I'm not allowed to save it -- or am I wrong?

Comment: If you ask permission of other user's that are authenticating the application (III(B)(4)), you could store their public profile url.

Answer (score -2):

//Rest API to fetch loggedin user details

var lkdURL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,location:(name),email-address,first-name,last-name)?oauth2_access_token="+LinkedSecurityKey+"&callback=yourfunction";

AJAX(lkdURL); // ajax call