# Is it possible to get my personal info from linkedin api without oauth?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm setting up a personal page, and I would like to display my past work experiences and other data I have on linked-in so it is automatically updated when I update my linked-in profile. Is this possible without having to do `oauth`? I just want my own data.

Comment: Is there any additional information I can provide to help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As the company says on [their REST API page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api):

> In order for your applications to access LinkedIn member data and/or act on their behalf, **they must be authenticated**.  LinkedIn relies on the industry standard OAuth 2.0 protocol for granting access, due to its simplicity and ease of implementation.

See also this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353950/is-there-a-way-to-access-linkedin-api-without-a-user).

This doesn't mean, however, that OAuth can't be handled for you:

> As a convenience, if you are developing a front-end [JavaScript](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) or
>   [Android](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk) application, we provide SDKs to handle the authentication
>   process for you.
>
> Additionally, there are several 3rd party libraries available in the
>   open source community that abstract the OAuth 2.0 authentication
>   process for you in every major programming language.

As for the major languages they support, LinkedIn provides walkthroughs in PHP, Python, and Java on their [API Get Started page](https://github.com/linkedin/api-get-started).